# Sistema de noticias com upload de imagem em PHP - quando não tem imagem!

Tags: php, mysqli, file-upload

Estou montando um sistema de notícias e no painel de adm para cadastro hoje, o código funciona da seguinte forma:
Cadastra o titulo/texto/imagem/ e torna ele ativo/inativo na situação: Que no caso o inativo utiliza como rascunho.
Tudo ok, funciona perfeitamente.
O detalhe é que com o código que tenho de upload de imagens, somente realiza o cadastro da noticia com upload de imagem.
Gostaria de inserir uma verificação, que se não tem imagem carregada, passa igual e faz o cadastro da noticia sem imagem.

Segue o código:

```
<?php
    include_once("../../conexao/conexao.php");
    $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
    $texto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['texto']);
    $situacao_noticia_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['situacao_noticia_id']);

    $arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];
    $caminho = "../../../imagens/noticia/";

    $_UP['pasta'] = $caminho;
    //Tamanho máximo do arquivo em Bytes
    $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*5; //5mb

    //Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
    $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
    $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o limite';
    $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especificado';
    $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
    $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

    //Verfica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe mensagem de erro
    if($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0){
        die("Não foi possivel fazer o upload, erro: <br>". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
        exit; //para a execução do script
    }


    //Fazer a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
    if($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']){   
        echo "
            <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$dominioadm/administrativo.php?link=31'>
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"ERRO! Não foi possivel cadastrar a notícia tente novamente!\");
            </script>
        ";  
    }


else {
// Codigo de inserção
$sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (nome, texto, situacao_noticia_id, imagem, created) VALUES ('{$nome}', '{$texto}', '{$situacao_noticia_id}', '{$arquivo}', NOW())";

// Converte e Executa a query
$inserir = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar.

Comment: Você que escreveu o código? Qual foi a dificuldade de fazer o que precisa?

Comment: Não tenho certeza do que fazer, se realizo um check no campo do arquivo, ou se insiro um if para verificar?

Comment: Qual a diferença entre "realizar um check" ou "inserir um if"?

Comment: check no input, tipo verificar se tem algum arquivo carregado no form, ou um if no processamento.

Comment: mais fácil verificar se foi carregado a imagem se sim, mesmo assim continua. Vou corrigir seu código pra vc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcelo Rossi, conforme já existe no seu código o retorno 4 do `array erros` é a verificação se há arquivo carregado pelo `input file`. Neste caso é só vc alterar esta parte do seu código:

```
//Verfica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe mensagem de erro
    if($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0 and $_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 4){
        die("Não foi possivel fazer o upload, erro: <br>". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
        exit; //para a execução do script
    }
```

Da maneira acima irá cadastrar a notícia sem imagem.

Comment: Perfeito - mais simples do que imaginava. O detalhe é não saber observar o próprio código. kkkkkkk - Obrigado @Leandro Alfredo

Comment: @MarceloRossi Estamos juntos